# PHP Version 5.2.17

Tags: php, web-hosting

I'm new to PHP development. After I signed up new hosting package, I found that my web host is using OLD PHP, that is PHP Version 5.2.17! The latest version is 5.4.14/5.3.24

What should I do now? Should I change the webhost or actually PHP Version 5.2.17 good enough for web development? Please advise the pros and cons of sticking with old version.

Comment: Hello John, Php 5.4 has better improvements and fixes which is why it is good to update in it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a shared webhosting environment, ie. you can only install software via things through a web interface, then yeah, change hosting providers. Even if you can manage to get a more up to date php running for yourself, you will be hosed if someone else on the same box gets hacked.

Same story if you are on a shared hosting box(multiple people logged into the same OS instance), but you are only chroot jailed. The system can still get compromised, causing you problems.

If you are on a XEN/VPS virtual machine instance, then yeah, upgrade that php.

Comment: yes, I'm using shared hosting.

Comment: Yeah, then I would recommend switching. If it's early enough, get a refund.

You can get XEN hosting for very cheap through providers like:

http://prgmr.com/xen/

(Disclaimer, I host with them currently)

Comment: thanks for advice. Some keyboard monkeys like the moderator just can not have a life. Where are you come from, Wing Tack? I'm Wong too from Malaysia.

Comment: @John Your question was closed because it's not about computer software or hardware that you own or control, but about web hosters and software development. [webmasters.SE] generally deals with these kinds of topics. Please read the [FAQ] for more info.

Comment: @slhck do you have enough points to migrate this post to Webmasters? You are correct, it fits there better than superuser.

Comment: The question would only be closed at Webmasters for being low quality